# How to pause/resume an Observable?

Tags: android, rx-java

I am trying to implement paging with retrofit, but I am struggling to find how to pause an observable so that it does not continue requesting pages that are not needed.

Basic question is: can I tell an observable source to "pause" and "resume"?  I'm not talking about buffering or skipping, but rather I would like for the source observable to stop completely, ie: don't make any web requests, etc.

Below is some simulated code that I'm working with.  rangeObservable is the simulated webserver "pager", and timerObservable would be like receiving scroll events.

```
package example.wanna.be.pausable;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.Throwable;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import rx.Observable;
import rx.observables.ConnectableObservable;
import rx.Subscription;
import rx.Subscriber;

public class Main {

  private static ConnectableObservable rangeObservable;

  private static void setPaused(boolean paused) {
    // How do I pause/resume rangeObservable?
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    rangeObservable = Observable.range(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE).publish();
    Observable timerObservable = Observable.timer(2, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    rangeObservable.subscribe(new Subscriber<Integer>() {

      private int count = 0;

      public void onStart() {
        System.out.println("Range started");
      }

      public void onNext(Integer i) {
        System.out.println("Range: " + i);

        if (++count % 20 == 0) {
          System.out.println("Pausing");
          setPaused(true);
        }
      }

      public void onError(Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      public void onCompleted() {
        System.out.println("Range done");
      }

    });

    timerObservable.subscribe(new Subscriber<Long>() {

      public void onStart() {
        System.out.println("Time started");

        // I dont know where to put this
        // rangeObservable.connect();
      }

      public void onNext(Long i) {
        System.out.println("Timer: " + i);
        setPaused(false);
      }

      public void onError(Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      public void onCompleted() {
        System.out.println("Timer done");
      }

    });

    // for some reason I have to do this or it just exits immediately
    try {
      System.in.read();
    } catch(IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

}
```

Any guidance is appreciated!

Comment: If the values received while paused can be dropped, you could just use filter with an AtomicBoolean gate to allow passing values though or not.

Comment: I think the way to go would be to have an Observable that emits a value when you select a new 'page'. Determine what page it is, use that as a parameter for the Retrofit call.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to store your subscription and call unsubscribe/subscribe on it (haven't tested this fully but I think it should work, most of my changes in setPaused, might need to fix code duplication):

```
package example.wanna.be.pausable;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.Throwable;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import rx.Observable;
import rx.observables.ConnectableObservable;
import rx.Subscription;
import rx.Subscriber;

public class Main {

  private static ConnectableObservable rangeObservable;
  Subscription mSubscription;

  private static void setPaused(boolean pause) {
    if (pause) {
        mSubscription.unsubscribe()
    } else {
        mSubscription.subscribe(new Subscriber<Integer>() {

      private int count = 0;

      public void onStart() {
        System.out.println("Range started");
      }

      public void onNext(Integer i) {
        System.out.println("Range: " + i);

        if (++count % 20 == 0) {
          System.out.println("Pausing");
          setPaused(true);
        }
      }

      public void onError(Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      public void onCompleted() {
        System.out.println("Range done");
      }

    });
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    rangeObservable = Observable.range(0, Integer.MAX_VALUE).publish();
    Observable timerObservable = Observable.timer(2, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    mSubscription = rangeObservable.subscribe(new Subscriber<Integer>() {

      private int count = 0;

      public void onStart() {
        System.out.println("Range started");
      }

      public void onNext(Integer i) {
        System.out.println("Range: " + i);

        if (++count % 20 == 0) {
          System.out.println("Pausing");
          setPaused(true);
        }
      }

      public void onError(Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      public void onCompleted() {
        System.out.println("Range done");
      }

    });

    timerObservable.subscribe(new Subscriber<Long>() {

      public void onStart() {
        System.out.println("Time started");

        // I dont know where to put this
        // rangeObservable.connect();
      }

      public void onNext(Long i) {
        System.out.println("Timer: " + i);
        setPaused(false);
      }

      public void onError(Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }

      public void onCompleted() {
        System.out.println("Timer done");
      }

    });

    // for some reason I have to do this or it just exits immediately
    try {
      System.in.read();
    } catch(IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

}
```

Also at the end you have:

```
// for some reason I have to do this or it just exits immediately
        try {
          System.in.read();
        } catch(IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The reason for this is that in the main() function the subscriptions are kicked off asynchronously, so your program reaches the end of main and then exits because there is no more code to run (since your observables run on a different thread).